# date format picture ends before converting entire input string error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, procedure

I have this procedure:

```
create or replace Procedure return_rows_LECTURE_BY_DATE (in_date in date, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As

Begin
     OPEN out_cursor for
     select *
     FROM COURSE_LECTURE
     WHERE LECT_DATE_TIME_START >= to_timestamp(in_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
     and       LECT_DATE_TIME_START < to_timestamp(in_date+1, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
    ORDER BY LECT_DATE_TIME_START;
End;
```

input: date, output: lectures on this date.
The dates in the table (view) is TIMESTAMP.

I want to run this procedure. I tried this:

```
declare 
k SYS_REFCURSOR;
--t DATE:= to_date('2010-12-14:09:56:53', 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS') ;
res COURSE_LECTURE%rowtype; 
begin
return_rows_LECTURE_BY_DATE(to_date('2010-12-14', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),k);
loop
  FETCH  k into res;
  Exit when k%notFound;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res.COURSE_NAME );
  end loop;
end;
```

But I got this error:

> Error report - ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting
>   entire input string ORA-06512: at "HR.RETURN_ROWS_LECTURE_BY_DATE",
>   line 4 ORA-06512: at line 6
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are converting the date into a timestamp, by using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`, which takes a [character as a parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions213.htm#SQLRF06142). You should use [`CAST()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) instead, which converts one datatype to another; for instance:

```
WHERE LECT_DATE_TIME_START >= CAST(in_date AS TIMESTAMP)
```

You should be doing this with all of your conversions from dates to timestamps; so `to_timestamp(in_date+1, 'dd-mm-yyyy')` becomes `CAST((in_date + 1) AS TIMESTAMP)`.

Comment: Can you please tell me where? I don't understand.

Comment: It is help! It is work! but I will use @Maksim Sirothkin, because I don't know what is "CAST". Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a ridiculous reason @user3868442; especially when this is the correct answer. If you don't know about something [look it up in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with statement to_timestamp(in_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') the format provided is too short you can use it without any format condition to_timestamp(in_date).

Comment: This is incorrect and relies on implicit conversion, the results of which can change on a session-by-session basis.